# GParted Boots to Grub Console

Tags: grub2, gparted

I've made a **GParted** live USB and it boots into **grub** console mode instead of the **GUI** boot menu of **GParted**.

Doing anything wrong?

**Edit**:
Could it be possible that this isn't the boot menu from GParted but my actual grub not knowing what to do with the USB?

**Edit #2:**
It should boot into something like this
[image]

Comment: Is not it easier to boot from Ubuntu LiveUSB. Gparted is installed there. And use it from there?

Comment: Should be fine I guess yes, but I'm still interested why this is happening.

Comment: If it showing a installed Linux OS's grub, you need to get into the BIOS to select the USB to boot from. If the GParted menu shows but is not like the screenshot, they may have changed it.

Comment: @Wilf I have my BIOS set so that it boots USB first. With the USB stick inserted grub goes into console mode. Maybe there's something wrong with the GParted live USB.